# Windows: How to import when certificate and private key are in separate files?

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I am trying to import a certificate using the certmgr.msc snap-in.

My certificate is in a .crt file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDezCCAmMCCQDFkO/4a6XfiDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADB9MQswCQYDVQQGEwJT
...
ncpMXzlNEE77e45mpTC/WWgoqQb7XMI+S1iPbluBVw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The private key is in a .key file and I have the password:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,FE5EDCD941BAD3DF54D29902EAB5EE48

9zZcw6zCfL6u8/HuBD/a57GSjAYb3DYzdjN8colcbWDTOSBpmbilapKdXd/XmVlM
.....
rjxIMhRRKCtdN0WZHwKU9wO/sAzllrx9lyt7qeEc3wSYYMD6bvdFjA9CXE27eQqW
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The Import wizard only allows a single file to be selected. I tried to combine the above two files as shown into a single file, but the import ignores the private key.

I tried putting the RSA PRIVATE KEY part before the CERTIFICATE part, but import says `The file type is not recognizable.`

I read that the .pem file is just a container and can include both the certificate and the private key. What have I missed in combining the two files into one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. remove all non-base64 content from private key file between PEM header and footer. In a given case, remove these lines from private key file:

   Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
   DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,FE5EDCD941BAD3DF54D29902EAB5EE48
2. Rename key file to match the certificate file name, e.g. `mycert.pem` and `mycert.key`, where `mycert.pem` is public certificate file and `mycert.key` is private key file. And place them in same folder. Then run the following `certutil.exe` command:

.

```
certutil -mergepfx mycert.pem mycert.pfx
```

where `mycert.pfx` is output file for PFX. You will be prompted to create PFX protection password.

Comment: PEM Without key?

Comment: Oh my god, this is most simple and really working method to import PEM file to Windows. One million likes to this author!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is also quite easy to do with openssl.

```
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert.pem -inkey mycert.key -out mycert.pfx
```